# Quasar Quploader failed upload with upload-fcatory

Tags: quasar-framework, quasar

QUploader fails even AFTER promise is resolved and @fail event is triggered (the progress bar is red in color and stuck at 99% if updateProgress is set to 1).

```
 <q-uploader
  :url="url"
  :upload-factory="uploadFile"
  :send-raw="true"
  :headers="{ 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }"
  :no-content-type="true"
  @add="uploadFileAdded"
  @start="uploadStarted"
  @finish="uploadFinished"
  @uploaded="uploadedFile"
  @fail="uploadFailed"
  color="orange"
  text-color="black"
  auto-expand
  extensions=".csv"
  inverted-light
  float-label="Upload List"
  :multiple="false"
  :hide-upload-button="false"
  :hide-upload-progress="false"
  :clearable="true"
/>

uploadFile(file, updateProgress) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve("Hi");
  });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After careful reading, finally solved it.

The Upload factory needs to return the uploaded file.

```
uploadFile(file, updateProgress) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve(file);
  });
},
```

Comment: but how would you use this? let's say your `@add='uploadFile'` and inside you want to set a `This.file = file` how would you upload it? or send it in a request ?

Comment: Uploading or sending a request is done by the upload-factory function "uploadFile"